# Unable to locate element

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm not sure if my approach is correct. I am trying to locate the value 'Arty' using a Name selector.

```
<button class="facet-button btn-large selected ng-scope keyword-facet" ng-click="removeFacet(sf)" ng-repeat="sf in selectedFacetsList">Arty</button>

// Then I remove 'Arty' from my search

[Then(@"I remove '(.*)' from my search")]
public static void RemoveAFacetButton(string searchName)
{
  var button = Driver.Instance.FindElements(By.cssSelector(".selected-facets-slide button")); 
  var itemToRemove = Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.Name(searchName));
  itemToRemove.Click();
}
```

error: Unable to locate element: {"method":"name","selector""Arty"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `name` attribute present on this `button` element. Instead use an XPath locator:

```
Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.XPath(string.Format("//button[. = '{0}']", searchName)));
```

Comment: Sorry about that copy and paste. What I am hoping to do is capture the value of 'SearchName' from my specflow step and pass it to the variable 'itemToRemove'. I want to avoid specifying a hard coded value. Hope that makes sense?

Comment: @AkifTahir well, still the answer applies, there is no "name" attribute on the button. The XPath I've proposed should match the button.

Comment: Thanks @alecxe that worked fine :) If I had multiple buttons and wanted to click on a particular one, is there a way to pass the name of my parameter 'searchName' into the XPath?